# How to deploy a nuxt app on a sub url with nginx

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js

On root url / i have a php application
I want to deply my nuxt app under /cartographie

my php application is in folder /var/www/applications/bottin/public

and nux app in /var/www/applications/carto-nuxt

But when I access to https://bottin.marche.be/cartographie it'a 404 error

What I must change ?

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name bottin.marche.be;

    root /var/www/applications/bottin/public;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";

    #Proxy Config
    location /cartographie {
        proxy_pass http://nuxt; # equal to server 127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }

    location / {
        # my php application
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }    
    
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php;
        #....
    }

}
```

My repo https://github.com/acmarche/carto-nuxt

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I founded

in nuxt.config.ts add NUXT_APP_BASE_URL

```
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
            NUXT_APP_BASE_URL: process.env.NUXT_APP_BASE_URL || '/'
        },
    },
```